# Phonegap for android store user credentials locally and pass in json for notifications

Tags: android, json, cordova, notifications, local-storage

I've built some pretty straight forward apps earlier using phonegap for android.

Now i'm building one that will need statusbar notifications from a background service per user.
Using phonegaps backgroundservice plugin, im able to get notifications through the example twitter feed.

> getMethod = new
>   HttpGet("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=phonegap&rpp=1&page1");

It works as expected, but i'm having big troubles with it.

1 - im not good with json
2 - ive yet to figure out how to store user credentials( user id f.example) on phone.

So lets say i want to build my own json file, myjson.php. in my java class, i cant pass a userid since this is not stored locally, and im unable to fetch it. my httpget would be:

> getMethod = new
>   HttpGet("http://domain.com/myjson.php");

Myjson.php would serve me any new messages, so i have to have a way of specifying which user is requesting the file. Concidering it is all through sql, it has to be the same values. 
php sessions wont cut it as phones often clears caches and forgets user credentials.

How can i do this? local sql? xml? 
And if i manage to store the user credentials locally, how can i add these to my httpget request?

Any help and pointers are greatly appreciated as ive read and read and read and now = stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data locally using LocalStorage. It's very simple. (Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Thanks for replying, and you are right! :)
Im testing out a sqlite approach and a localStorage approach. My problem now is fetching the values stored from the native app using these two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is you dont really do json. You just ask for a content encoded in Jason. Look at the native code contained [here](http://code.Google.com/p/android-json-rpc).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying :) Ive been able to get it working now, json and all. Just had to get to understand json and the backgroundservice abit better. The localstorage did the trick for storing a tiny bit of info locally per device.